# Grouping objects during retrieving data

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, vue.js

I have the following firebase database.

```
  {
      "orders" : [ null, {
        "date" : "2018-07-09 10:07:18",
        "item" : "apple",
        "price" : 30 },
        {
        "date" : "2018-06-09 10:07:18",
        "item" : "bread",
        "price" : 25 
        },
        {
        "date" : "2018-06-13 10:07:18",
        "item" : "milk",
        "price" : 25 
        },
        {
        "date" : "2018-07-05 10:07:18",
        "item" : "cheese",
        "price" : 50 
        }
       ]
    }
```

I want to retrieving data in a Vue project, but I dont know how. There are orders in different times and I want to use the groupByChild('date') method, but this returns 4 objects because the dates are unique. I want grouping the orders among the month of the order dates. How Could I grouping the objects among the 7-8. caracter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a part of the ISO date, year and month for grouping.

```js
var data = { orders: [null, { date: "2018-07-09 10:07:18", item: "apple", price: 30 }, { date: "2018-06-09 10:07:18", item: "bread", price: 25 }, { date: "2018-06-13 10:07:18", item: "milk", price: 25 }, { date: "2018-07-05 10:07:18", item: "cheese", price: 50 }] },
    groups = data.orders.reduce((r, o) => {
        var key;
        if (!o) {
            return r;
        }
        key = o.date.slice(0, 7);
        r[key] = r[key] || [];
        r[key].push(o);
        return r;    
    }, Object.create(null));
    
console.log(groups);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. Let me ask a last question. How can filter the arrays with '2018-07' month?

Comment: sorry for delay, take `data.orders.filter(o => o && o.date.startsWith('2018-07'))` with a previous check for the object.